# Strip all elements from array where they occur less than twice

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
[0] = 2
[1] = 8
[2] = 7
[3] = 7
```

And I want to end up with an array that looks like:

```
[0] = 7
[1] = 7
```

Basically, remove all elements where they occur less than twice.

Is their a PHP function that can do this?

Comment: array_count_values() followed by a filter with the count >1 followed by an array_fill() might work

Comment: can you clarify the question, what you want to do? to remove the top 2 elements..!

Comment: Close vote lonely without comment backup...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this,

```
$ar1=array(2,3,4,7,7);
    $ar2=array();
    foreach (array_count_values($ar1) as $k => $v) {
        if ($v > 1) {
            for($i=0;$i<$v;$i++)
            {
            $ar2[] = $k;
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($ar2);
```

output

`Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 7 )`

Comment: Perfect thanks! fullybaked unfortunately didn't reset the array keys.

Comment: Sorry, what? You must be tremendously joking.

Comment: ...What do you need two arrays for? Say hi to memory waste. What do you need two loops for? Say hi to CPU drainage.

Comment: Also the answer is wrong. Question was *"Is their a PHP function that can do this?"*. And we all know the correct answer, it is *"No"*. The rest of this "question" is not a programming question at all. - Not seeing it hair-thin, stripping elements does not imply to-renumber array keys.

Comment: @imperium2335: sure he does, you just missed to use the built-in function for that, I edited his answer for you. Also leave a comment if you have a problem with an answer, not just wait until you get spoon-fed.

Comment: @imperium2335 you can change the accept answer you should select most appropriate

Comment: Still I don't think people should downvote so much, I've consumed my daily 40 upvotes, waiting for the time limit to upvote this one.

Comment: @Yadav Chetan +1 for mercy. Your answer worked "straight out of the box" for me, that's why I accepted initially.

Comment: +1, there is always more than one way to do things, in this case it would probably be the easiest to read. The CPU argument made me laugh - as if it would make any noticeable difference....

Comment: I do need two arrays for the thing I'm making, this is just a tiny part of it. If I need to I will use one letter variable names and recycle every variable to save a few bytes of memory.

Comment: @hakre The question is also in my example.

Comment: @imperium2335: Re-using variable names does not really save memory. And the problem I highlighted is that you didn't comment on the answers that were already there but instead waited until you could pick one. That is really counter-productive to the users here that take the time to actually answer you.

Comment: @hakre But not counter-productive to those who seek the most effective answer to the problem. Do not misunderstand me however, I greatly appreciate all answers and where I learn something I happily up-vote.

Comment: @imperium2335: Most efficient solution? Your second loop is completely superfluous.

Comment: Also, @AlexP, the moment your array contains 100 elements, you'll actually *like* doing 100 operations rather than 10 000.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work, although you could probably improve it with array_reduce and an anonymous function

```
<?php

$originalArray = array(2, 8, 7, 7);

foreach (array_count_values($originalArray) as $k => $v) {
    if ($v < 2) {
        $originalKey = array_search($k, $originalArray);
        unset($originalArray[$originalKey]);
    }
}

var_dump(array_values($originalArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of `array_count_values` (which will give you an associative array with the value as the key, and the times it occurs as the value), followed by a simple loop, as follows:

```
$frequency = array_count_values($yourArray);
foreach ($yourArray as $k => $v) {
   if (!empty($frequency[$v]) && $frequency[$v] < 2) {
      unset($yourArray[$k]);
   }
}
```

I did not test it, but I reckon it works out of the box. Please note that you will loop over your results twice and not N^2 times, unlike an `array_search` method. This can be further improved, and this is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

```
$testData = array(2,8,7,7,5,6,6,6,9,1);

$newArray = array();
array_walk(
    array_filter(
        array_count_values($testData),
        function ($value) {
            return ($value > 1);
        }
    ),
    function($counter, $key) use (&$newArray) {
        $newArray = array_merge($newArray,array_fill(0,$counter,$key));
    }
);

var_dump($newArray);
```

Though it'll give a strict standards warning. To avoid that, you'd need an interim stage:

```
$testData = array(2,8,7,7,5,6,6,6,9,1);

$newArray = array();
$interim = array_filter(
    array_count_values($testData),
    function ($value) {
        return ($value > 1);
    }
);
array_walk(
    $interim,
    function($counter, $key) use (&$newArray) {
        $newArray = array_merge($newArray,array_fill(0,$counter,$key));
    }
);

var_dump($newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

This was actually harder to do than i thought...anyway...

```
 $input  = array(2, 8, 7, 7, 9, 9, 10, 10);
 $output = array();

 foreach(array_count_values($input) as $key => $value) {
   if ($value > 1) $output = array_merge($output, array_fill(0, $value, $key));
 }
 var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Not sure why you need that ternary in the array_merge() line: `$output = array_merge($output, array_fill(0, $value, $key));` should work perfectly well

Comment: So it does, thank you. I was under the impression you had to be explicit with the starting index in `array_fill`

Comment: Only if you plan on using `$output = $output + array_fill(0, $value, $key);` because you'd get a key clash

Answer (score 1):

```
$arrMultipleValues = array('2','3','5','7','7','8','2','9','11','4','2','5','6','1');

function array_not_unique($input)    
{
    $duplicatesValues = array();

    foreach ($input as $k => $v)
    {
        if($v>1)
        {
        $arrayIndex=count($duplicatesValues);
        array_push($duplicatesValues,array_fill($arrayIndex, $v, $k));
        }    
    }

    return $duplicatesValues;
}

$countMultipleValue = array_count_values($arrMultipleValues);
print_r(array_not_unique($countMultipleValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is their [sic!] a PHP function that can do this?

No, PHP has no built-in function (yet) that can do this out of the box.

That means, if you are looking for a function that does this, it needs to be in PHP userland. I would like to quote a comment under your question which already suggest you how you can do that if you are looking for that instead:

> array_count_values() followed by a filter with the count >1 followed by an array_fill() might work

By [Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker) [5 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318368/strip-all-elements-from-array-where-they-occur-less-than-twice/16318466#comment23366622_16318368)

If this sounds a bit cryptic to you, those functions he names are actually built-in function in PHP, so I assume this comes most close to the no, but answer:

- [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/array_count_values)
- [`array_fill()`](http://php.net/array_fill)

Answer (score 0):

This does the job, maybe not the most efficient way. I'm new to PHP myself :)

```
   <?php
$element = array();
$element[0] = 2;
$element[1] = 8;
$element[2] = 7;
$element[3] = 7;

$count = array_count_values($element);
var_dump($element);
var_dump($count);

$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveArrayIterator($count));

$result = array();
foreach ($it as $key=>$val){
    if ($val >= 2){
        for($i = 1; $i <= $val; $i++){
            array_push($result,$key);
        }
    }
}
var_dump($result);

?>
```

EDIT: var_dump is just so you can see what's going on at each stage